# como contar los numeros que me muestra dentro de mi listview y mostrar en un textview el resultado total

Tags: java, android-studio

Hola amigos como puedo realizar una suma dentro de un lisview y mostar en un textview[![que el total de pago se muestre en la parte de abajo][![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

Hola amigos como puedo realizar una suma dentro de un lisview y mostar en un textview[![que el total de pago se muestre en la parte de abajo][![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
Hola amigos como puedo realizar una suma dentro de un lisview y mostar en un textview[![que el total de pago se muestre en la parte de abajo][![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
Hola amigos como puedo realizar una suma dentro de un lisview y mostar en un textview[![que el total de pago se muestre en la parte de abajo][![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public class DetallePrestamo extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    private ListView listView;

    private String JSON_STRING;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detalle_prestamo);

        String id = "";
        Bundle exttras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (exttras != null) {
            id = exttras.getString("id");
        }
        TextView txtid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detallid);
        txtid.setText(id);

        //otro

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lisview);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        getJSON();
    }

    private void mostrar_cliente() {
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(ConfiActivities.TAGI_JSON_ARRAY);
            for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
                String idpago = jo.getString(ConfiActivities.TAGI_ID);
                //String nombre = jo.getString(ConfiActivities.TAGI_ID_NOMBRE);
                String fechapago = jo.getString(ConfiActivities.TAGI_FECHA);
                String total = jo.getString(ConfiActivities.TAGI_TOTAL);

                HashMap<String, String> contactos = new HashMap<>();
                contactos.put(ConfiActivities.TAGI_ID, idpago);
                //contactos.put(ConfiActivities.TAGI_ID_NOMBRE, nombre);
                contactos.put(ConfiActivities.TAGI_FECHA, fechapago);
                contactos.put(ConfiActivities.TAGI_TOTAL, total);

                list.add(contactos);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            DetallePrestamo.this, list, R.layout.items_listardetalle,
            new String[]{ConfiActivities.TAGI_ID,ConfiActivities.TAGI_FECHA,ConfiActivities.TAGI_TOTAL},
            new int[]{R.id.detallid,R.id.fechadetall,R.id.totaldetal});
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
    private void getJSON(){
    class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
        ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(DetallePrestamo.this, "Cargando datos", "Espere...", false, false);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            JSON_STRING = s;
            mostrar_cliente();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            String s = rh.sendGetRequest(ConfiActivities.URL_GET_ALL);
            return s;
        }
    }
        GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
        gj.execute();
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       // HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        //String empId = map.get(ConfiActivities.TAGI_ID).toString();
        //intent.putExtra(ConfiActivities.EMP_ID, empId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar un extracto de tu codigo, como estas llenando el adaptador, para poder identificar que variables que estas utilizando

Comment: disculpa no se como enviarte no se utilizar bien la plataforma si deceas puedo enviarte el proyecto completo

Comment: debes escribirlo en este mismo medio, pero debes leer bien esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting  pon tambien el codigo de como estas llenando tu adaptador, tambien si es posible, de donde fue que vistes la forma que usaste para realizar esto, **links**

Comment: @GrsnChml alli esta amigo disculpa

Comment: `int total += jo.getInt(ConfiActivities.TAGI_TOTAL);` de esta manera esta manera estarias sumando lo que trae

Comment: @GrsnChml que hago alli amigo

Comment: ahi lo que estas haciendo es que estas llenando el total con las variables que vienen en el json, ese lo podes poner en el **TextView**, el que dice **_Total_** pero lo que debes hacer es crear una variable global por ejemplo **int totalTotales** y la vas a llenar con total
**totalTotales  += jo.getInt(ConfiActivities.TAGI_TOTAL);** y despues `textViewTotal.setText(String.ValueOf(totalTotales));`

Comment: amigo disculpa no le entiendo totalTotales += jo.getInt(ConfiActivities.TAGI_TOTAL); me sale error en el +

Comment: que error te da? ese codigo tu lo creaste?

Comment: si  pero me dices que agregue este signo + me manda error al agregarlo

Comment: si, pero debes crear una variable global para poder llenarla para eso usaras esos signos `+=`

Comment: amigo gracias ya me salio eres un crack

Comment: gracias, es un placer ayudarte

Comment: amigo puedes ayudarme en algo? responde si estas ahi

Comment: coméntame que problema estas teniendo